# FFT implementation produces a glitch

Tags: android, c++, c, fft

I'm getting a strange glitch in a FFT graph for white noise:

[image]

I've checked with reference program and while noise file seems to be fine.
Is it a bug in implementation?

```
void four1(float data[], int nn, int isign) {
    int n, mmax, m, j, istep, i;
    float wtemp, wr, wpr, wpi, wi, theta;
    float tempr, tempi;

    n = nn << 1;
    j = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i += 2) {
        if (j > i) {
            tempr = data[j];
            data[j] = data[i];
            data[i] = tempr;
            tempr = data[j + 1];
            data[j + 1] = data[i + 1];
            data[i + 1] = tempr;
        }
        m = n >> 1;
        while (m >= 2 && j > m) {
            j -= m;
            m >>= 1;
        }
        j += m;
    }
    mmax = 2;
    while (n > mmax) {
        istep = 2 * mmax;
        theta = TWOPI / (isign * mmax);
        wtemp = sin(0.5 * theta);
        wpr = -2.0 * wtemp * wtemp;
        wpi = sin(theta);
        wr = 1.0;
        wi = 0.0;
        for (m = 1; m < mmax; m += 2) {
            for (i = m; i <= n; i += istep) {
                j = i + mmax;
                tempr = wr * data[j] - wi * data[j + 1];
                tempi = wr * data[j + 1] + wi * data[j];
                data[j] = data[i] - tempr;
                data[j + 1] = data[i + 1] - tempi;
                data[i] += tempr;
                data[i + 1] += tempi;
            }
            wr = (wtemp = wr) * wpr - wi * wpi + wr;
            wi = wi * wpr + wtemp * wpi + wi;
        }
        mmax = istep;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the size of the input `data`?

Comment: @molbdnilo the size of data is double the nn, each input number is a pair of actual_real_number and 0 for imaginary part

Comment: @tobi303 the question is most suited for a debug session to find out why it's happening... as it is, I don't expect anyone to actually implement a fast fourier transformation and give you the exact line that needs to be fixed.

Comment: You're indexing out-of-bounds in the second loop - [here](http://ideone.com/Hc7Pzg) is a program that prints `i + 1` and `j + 1`.

Comment: please place question updates as new text in the question itself, not in comments.

Comment: 1) please use meaningful variable names.  2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement* 3) separate code blocks (if, else, for, while, do...while, switch, case, default) by a single blank line.  4) please comment the code to indicate `why` or `current condition` at key points in the code.

Comment: in C, array offsets start with 0 and continue to (number of entries in array-1).   The posted code seems to believe the offsets for an array start with 1 and continue to the number of entries in array.  which misses processing array[0] and accesses trash beyond the end of the array, resulting in undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: what is the value of `TWOPI`?

Comment: the posted code contains several implicit conversions from` double` to `float`.  Suggest just make the `float` variable declarations into `double` variable declarations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from a few minor changes, this code appears to be taken out of the 2nd edition of Numerical Recipes in C. The documentation for this function (taken from the book) states:

> Replaces `data[1..2*nn]` by its discrete Fourier transform, if `isign` is input as 1; or replaces `data[1..2*nn]` by `nn` times its inverse discrete Fourier transform, if `isign` is input as −1.
>   `data` is a complex array of length `nn` or, equivalently, a real array of length `2*nn`. `nn` MUST be an integer power of 2 (this is not checked for!).

This implementation yields correct results, given an input array with 1-based indexing. You can choose to use the same indexing convention by allocating a C array of size `2*nn+1` and filling your array starting at index 1. Alternatively you could pass an array of size `2*nn` which has been fill starting at index 0, but calling `four1(data-1, nn, isign)` (notice the `-1` offset on the `data` array).